# Como carregar uma lista de objeto no flutter?

Tags: flutter

Por favor observem a lista de objetos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não consigo por falta de experiência capturar o **content** na minha consulta flutter. Falta somente isso para eu conseguir carregar perfeitamente a minha consulta essa foi minha tentativa, porém não seu certo.

```
@override
  Future<List<Discipulo>> findAllDiscipulo() async {
    List<Discipulo> discipulos = [];
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://endereçodaminhaaplicacao.com/discipulos'));
    
    final decoded = jsonDecode(response.body);

    Map<String, dynamic> data = decoded['content'];/*não consegue passa dessa linha*/

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {

      data.forEach((discipulosId, discipulos) {
        discipulos.add(
          Discipulo(
            codigo: discipulos['codigo'],
            nome: discipulos['nome'],
            dataNascimento: discipulos['dataNascimento'],
            logradouro: discipulos['logradouro'],
            origem: discipulos['origem'],
            telefone: discipulos['telefone'],
          ),
        );
      });

      return discipulos;
    }

    return [];
  }
```

Quando tiro o **content** ele fica assim;

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = decoded;/*Consegue passa dessa linha*/

if (response.statusCode == 200) {

  data.forEach((discipulosId, discipulos) {
    discipulos.add(
      Discipulo(
        codigo: discipulos['codigo'],/*Não consegue passa dessa linha por causa do "content"*/
        nome: discipulos['nome'],
        dataNascimento: discipulos['dataNascimento'],
        logradouro: discipulos['logradouro'],
        origem: discipulos['origem'],
        telefone: discipulos['telefone'],
      ),
    );
  });
```

Por favor como poderia fazer para conseguir lista o objeto corretamente?

Comment: Pelo que pude perceber, o content é um array né... Então você tem que receber um List<Map<String, dynamic>>

Comment: Isso mesmo.  Estou tentando fazer isso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altere a linha

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = decoded['content'];
```

para

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = decoded['content'];
```